# summarizing a vector from multiple data frames

Tags: r, apply, summary

I have five data frames with a different number of vectors. Vector `Q10` is present in all data frames (character; values = "Yes" or "No"). I currently check the contents of this variable this way:

```
table(mon1$Q10)
table(tue1$Q10)
table(wed1$Q10)
table(thr1$Q10)
table(fri1$Q10)
```

How can I do this more quickly? I can use a loop, but that also doesn't seem efficient. I imagine the apply functions hold the answer (I've placed my data frames into a list called `svylist`), but I haven't yet worked it out.

The resulting output should show counts of the "Yes" and "No" values for each data frame. A single table would be stellar, but even the output from the repeated `table()` functions above works fine.

Comment: `lapply(mget(c("mon1","tues1", "wed1","thur1","fri1")), "[[", "Q10")` or `lapply(mget(c("mon1","tues1", "wed1","thur1","fri1")), function(x) table(x$Q10))` to generate the tables

Comment: Also, consider moving all your datasets into a single list - that will simplify things.

Comment: @emilliman5 that gets close, but the outputs are not summary counts like `table()` provides.

Comment: @iod, thanks - just added my partial lapply solution to the question which does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine all your dataframes into a single list, and then access them using sapply:

```
days1<-list(mon=mon1,tue=tue1,wed=wed1,thr=thr1,fri=fri1)
sapply(days1, function(x) table(x$Q10))
```

Demonstration using two dataframes coz I'm lazy:

```
  mon tue
n    2   1
y    2   3
```